# IBM App Connect Toolkit and MQ missing libraries

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I was following IBM tutorial "Getting Started with IBM App Connect Enterprise 12". (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6sj2FR31PQM&t=1006s)

Great tutor, as IBM videos are. BUT :

"BIP2684E" : A component was configured to use IBM MQ, but required MQ libraries are not available.

I have MQ broker running locally in docker container (IBM dev image) and ACE toolkit with MQ-policy.

What do I need to do to have those missing libraries ?

Required libraries for IBM ACE Toolkit (server) to be able to connect to IBM MQ server ? Please ??

I have googled couple of hours and all I can find from IBM documentations is how to configure this and that.

But "missing libraries" ?!!?!

Comment: I have successfully followed the instructions of IBM tutorial video. Until I try to run ACE Toolkit FlowExcerciser, and get this "required MQ libraries are not available" error,.

Comment: And next question: I need to create / generate a deploy file (bar), to be able to deploy my integration application to ACE (integration) server, or one of those. Running on their own containers, each of them. Would those missing MQ (client ?) libraries be encluded in bar-file ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install MQ to use features that connect to MQ:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/12.0?topic=messages-interaction-between-app-connect-enterprise-mq

Comment: Yes I need IBM MQ client libraries to test ACE flows with ACE Toolkit. But that link does no help.

Answer (score 0):

It should be sufficient to download & unpack an IBM MQ Client (e.g. from [IBM Fix Central](https://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm%7EWebSphere&product=ibm/WebSphere/WebSphere%20MQ&release=9.2.0.0&platform=All&function=fixid&fixids=*IBM-MQC-Redist-*)) and include the `bin/` directory in your Path environment variable.

If this does not work, you should also set the environment variable `MQ_INSTALLATION_PATH` to the base folder of the expanded MQ Client package, e.g. `MQ_INSTALLATION_PATH=C:\Apps\IBM\9.2.0.8-IBM-MQC-Redist-Win64`.

(Note that this is possibly a duplicate question of [IBM App Connect Toolkit with MQ libraries on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75290132/ibm-app-connect-toolkit-with-mq-libraries-on-windows-10) (or vice versa).)