# IBM App Connect Toolkit with MQ libraries on Windows 10

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I have IBM App Connect Enterprice Toolkit on my Win 10 machine. Works OK.

But now I need to use IBM MQ queues. And that seems to need some MQ libraries installed on my setup.

How can I install those missing libraries?

There probably is a installation package, but I just cant find one.

Comment: Please dont point me to IBM doc page with 219 links to other pages, each of those pointing to 93 other doc pages. Just how to install MQ libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main link you want is https://developer.ibm.com/articles/mq-downloads/, which will lead you to https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/mq-connect-app-queue-manager-windows/ which will lead you to https://ibm.biz/mqdevwindows

The final one is the download, but I'd recommend going through the steps in the second link for help on how to get it all set up.